# How to use multiple cores on pyspark (from python script)

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm using pyspark to make some sql queries to a parquet file. I need to use multiple cores, but i didn't find any useful information. Here's the code i'm using. As you can see i set to 3 the number of cores, but when i run the script, i can see on htop that there's only 1 core in use. How can i solve this?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL tests") \
        .config("spark.executor.cores", 3) \
        .getOrCreate()
# Check conf
for item in spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll():
    print(item)
# Open file and create dataframe
filename = "gs://path/to/file.parquet"
df = spark.read.parquet(filename)
# Create table
df.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")
# Query
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM myTable")
sqlDF.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

From my understanding you use spark standalone(only in your machine not a cluster).

try:

```
from pyspark import sql


spark = (
    sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "32g")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "32g")

    ...

    .getOrCreate()
)
```

`*` in `local[*]` means use all avaliable cores. You can give a number like `local[3]`.

Comment: Thank you, but it keeps using only 1 core. Other ideas?

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me using the local[*]. 
I used this: SparkConf().setAppName("").setMaster("local[*]")